# IE11 Javascript on-change event not working with html form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, internet-explorer-11, jquery-events

I'm making simple application for record leave dates. With this application I have to select start date and end date of the leave and then calculate all the business dates in between those two days. So far my codes working Chrome and Firefox perfectly. I'm using jQuery UI date-picker for select two dates and use second date-picker on-change event for count dates and display it inside html input box.

With IE this function is broken and after I set two dates using date time picker on-change event not firing

This is sample of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
              $( function() {
                $( "#startd" ).datepicker({beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends , dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
              } );
            
              $( function() {
                $( "#endd" ).datepicker({beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends , dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
              } );

 function getBusinessDatesCount(startDate, endDate) {
    var count = 0;
    var curDate = startDate;
    while (curDate <= endDate) {
        var dayOfWeek = curDate.getDay();
        if(!((dayOfWeek == 6) || (dayOfWeek == 0)))
           count++;
        curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return count;
}
            </script>
            
    
            <form action='reqprocess.php' method='post'>
                <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>
            <tr>
                        <td id="td2">Start</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="datepicker" class='form-control' id="startd" required onchange="calnumofdays()" /></td>
                    </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td id="td1">End</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="datepicker2" class='form-control' id="endd" onchange="calnumofdays()" /></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Days</td>
                        <td><input type="number" name='leavehmd' class='form-control' id="lhmd"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
            function calnumofdays() {           
           
            var startDate = $(startd).datepicker("getDate");
            var endDate = $(endd).datepicker("getDate");
        
            var numOfDates = getBusinessDatesCount(startDate, endDate);
            $('#lhmd').val(numOfDates);
            //alert(numOfDates);
            $('div#result').text(numOfDates);
          }
        </script>
```

How can I fix this? this code is working perfectly fine in chrome and firfox. And when I remove form tags in html it start to work in IE too.

Comment: Could you try adding the onchange listeners with JavaScript? Maybe IE is messing up from using the attributes?

Comment: I already tried that too but no luck !!

Comment: Okay. Where is the `calnumofdays` function?

Comment: And is that function actually running?

Comment: Yes running perfectly with chrome and firefox

Comment: But _in IE_ does it run? Log something from inside the function and see if it fires.

Comment: If it does, then add more logs to different parts of the logic to see which part _isn't_ running.

Comment: Yes!! without HTML form tags function work fine. I don't know why

Comment: Interesting. So if you could simplify the problem down, maybe it would be easier to figure out. All you need is a form, a text box inside it, and the onchange event hooked up to log to the console. This would prove or disprove that it's not some other part of the code but specifically IE messing up with form elements.

Comment: yes I can confirm it only brakes with from elements. without form elements everything fine !!

Comment: And the code has almost all been stripped out? It's definitely not the jQuery plugin or anything?

Comment: I'm sorry what you mean in striped out ? I don't have much knowledge in javascripts and jquery but the code is working perfectly without HTML form tags. I heard that different Jquery versions that with support for IE11 and do I need to add those versions too ?

Comment: Just for testing this IE bug. So just make a HTML file somewhere, with code like [this](https://gist.github.com/wthit56/d7390837c33b45ba5e81ec3b9eecc3bd), and then open it in IE11. This will help you test out this bug and figure out which parts are actually causing it and which parts are incidental (like complex JS not working).

Comment: Worked !! thanks to you I got the error from console. I missed the double quotes of #startd and #endd. but when I copy and past one of answers below twice!! it not worked !!. Now It's working :) IDK why. anyway Thank you very much for helping me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit these parts on calnumofdays and it will work...

```
function calnumofdays() {           

            var startDate = $("#startd").datepicker("getDate"); //edit these
            var endDate = $("#endd").datepicker("getDate"); //edit these

            var numOfDates = getBusinessDatesCount(startDate, endDate);
            $('#lhmd').val(numOfDates);
            //alert(numOfDates);
            $('div#result').text(numOfDates);
          }
```

Comment: use f12 developer tools to debug.... i just copy pasta ur code and found the issue try it your self :)

Comment: I'm Extremely sorry for it. I missed it in only here not in my code. I accidentally deleted it when I edit the code in stack-overflow

Comment: code still works perfectly in other browsers. I think this is due to on-change event not firing with form element. But I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: i run ur code on IE-11 and this works after i correct the mistargeted elements on function calnumofdays()... are you really testing???

Comment: Thanks !! your solution working perfectly. I tested it before but somehow I missed some parts. but now it's working !!